# How do I pull from my "public" git server to bring my broken local "master" up to date?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a local "master" git repository. Every few hours, I 'git push' my changes to a server from which I then pull to my client machines.  Well, I accidentally used GITK to rollback my local "master" repository one version too far.

What are the steps to pull the last committed version back from the server and still have my local version behave "masterfully"?

Comment: Could just pull from the server to one of the clients, then copy over the pulled result and re-commit it to the master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your local master is still clean, *i.e.*, no local changes, but some number of commits behind master on the server repo, you need only pull from it:

```
git pull server master
```

In the above command, `server` is the name of the remote that other clients pull from (or you could use its URL instead).

Answer (score 2):

First, stash your existing changes:

```
git stash
```

Then, run (considering that the remote from which you want to update your local repository to be named `origin`):

```
git remote update origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Apply the stashed changes:

```
git stash pop
```